# How to Install conscript in Windows

Tags: scala, scalatra, giter8

Conscript is needed for giter8  to check out project templates directly from Github and as Scalatra.org states

> is recommended way to generate Scalatra project skeletons.

When conscript-0.4.4.jar is ran error "Error downloading sbt-launch-0.13.0 happens".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sbt-launch-0.13.0.jar was removed from sbt site. so you have to:

1. Install sbt from the official site.
2. Copy "sbt-launch.jar" from "C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin" into "C:\Users{Username}.conscript"
3. Make **another** copy of "sbt-launch.jar" in "C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin" and rename it to "sbt-launch-0.13.0.jar"
4. Run your conscript installation jar ("conscript-0.4.4-1.jar") and wait for it to finish.
5. Add "C:\Users{Username}\bin" to your PATH environment variable.