# Scalatra will not run on Windows

Tags: scalatra

I have been working on a Scalatra project on a Linux environment and would now like to switch to a Windows environment. I've transferred the project folder to my Windows directory. Using Cygwyn, I cd to the Scalatra project and type

```
./sbt
> jetty:start
```

Nothing happens at this point. I have waited 10 minutes but nothing is printed to the console. I am having a hard time thinking of what might be the cause, since the exact same project works fine on Linux. Anyone have a Scalatra project working on Windows and remember whether there were any Windows-specific steps to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this on a fresh Windows 10 Professional VM in virtual box.  I only allocated 1 CPU and 4 GB RAM, which may have made things unnecessarily slow.  I was logged in as administrative user `testvm`

I always started new command prompts after modifying environment variables.  All of my command prompts were run as administrator...  I don't know whether that was necessary.

In general, these instructions were a good start: [How to Install conscript in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837278/how-to-install-conscript-in-windows), followed by http://scalatra.org/getting-started/first-project.html

- installed the [java developers kit](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-windows-i586.exe), by visiting [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-21)

  - or [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- added the JDK's bin folder (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin`) to the end of the `PATH` system variable
- started a new command prompt and ran `set` to review the `PATH` environment variable, and ran `javac –version` as an additional sanity check
- downloaded and installed [sbt for windows](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html).  Didn't make any manual changes to the `PATH` at this point.
- conscript (or giter8?) requires bash (and/or git?), so I installed [git for windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win).  I did a default install, except I specified that git and "optional Linux components" should all be accessible form the windows prompt.  I also added `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` to the PATH environment variable.  I’m not sure if either or both of those tweaks are required.
- downloaded the latest [conscript jar](https://dl.bintray.com/foundweekends/maven-releases/org/foundweekends/conscript/conscript_2.11/0.5.1/conscript_2.11-0.5.1-proguard.jar).  I got a warning that the download might not be safe and accepted anyway.
- double clicked the conscript jar to run it.  A nice graphical dialogue box came up and eventually told me that a cs.bat script had been created in `C:\Users\testvm\.conscript\bin\cs.bat`.  100% CPU use continued for several minutes after this and eventually I clicked the close button (X) in the upper right of the conscript installer dialogue.

  - *When I installed conscript in another system more recently, it went quickly but I got a warning that cs.bat might not be on the system path.*
- ran conscript to obtain giter8.  I have found that giter8 v 0.8 fails to build the skeleton project with an error like "parameters cannot contain '.'", so I specifically asked for v 0.7.2:  `C:\Users\testvm\.conscript\bin\cs.bat foundweekends/giter8/0.7.2`
- ran giter8 to install the skeleton scalatra project:  `C:\Users\testvm\.conscript\bin\g8.bat scalatra/scalatra-sbt`
- accepted all of the default parameters
- turned off the windows firewall, the defender real-time protection, and started a new cmd prompt as administrator.  I don’t know if ***any*** of those are necessary
- ran sbt:  `c:\Users\testvm\my-scalatra-web-app\sbt`

  - *Going through this more recently, `my-scalatra-web-app` was installed into `c:\Windows\System32\my-scalatra-web-app`, but I was able to copy it to the top of `C:\`.  `cd`'ing in there and running just `sbt` gave an error message, because there's a `sbt` file in that folder, but it's not a windows executable.  So I entered `"c:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin\sbt.bat"`.  Subsequently, that directory was added to my PATH environment variable, so I could just enter `sbt.bat`*
- ***waited*** as components downloaded, installed and compiled
- when the sbt `>` prompt reappeared, entered `jetty:start` and waited some more
- eventually, the following appeared:

  2017-05-09 07:31:15.101:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@bffcb98{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
  2017-05-09 07:31:15.101:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @8698ms
- Opened `http://localhost:8080` in a web browser and saw `Hello, world!`